# BS3 input-group-addon taller than input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a footer on my page, with a Newsletter signin form.
The input-group-addon is getting bigger than the input itself ONLY on intern pages, the index page displays correctly, even with the same CSS file, and same footer structure.

[image]

Again, same structure, same css...

This is my whole foooter structure:

```
<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer>
    <div class="footer" id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Tecnologia</h3>
                     <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Servidores</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Programação</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Segurança</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Backups</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Suporte</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Helpdesk</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Painel de controle</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">F.A.Q</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Contatos</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Engine</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Valores</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Missão</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Nosso time</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Política de uso</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Produtos</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Sistemas</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Websites</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Mídias Sociais</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Hospedagem</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                    <h3>Newsletter</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <form action="" method="post" role="form">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="" name="" placeholder="digite seu e-mail">
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;" />
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bootsnipp"><i id="social-fb" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/bootsnipp"><i id="social-tw" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://plus.google.com/+Bootsnipp-page"><i id="social-yt" class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="pull-left">Copyright © 2017 - ENGINE Sistemas. All rights reserved | <a href="http://www.enginesistemas.com.br" target="_blank">ENGINE Sistemas</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

The footer is responsive too...

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: i guess we need to check your css

Comment: Seeing the css for the input would be helpful but off the top of my head; from the screenshot provided; I would say there is a border around the envelope div which could be causing the problem. A way of fixing this would be try and remove any borders and reset any margin/padding or you can give the `input.form-control` class a height to match that f `input-group-button`

Comment: I'm not treating the inputs on CSS, it's pure BS3, that's the stranger part. And why it would work on index but not on other pages?

Comment: I noticed as I resize or test on other resolution it fix itself or bug itself. o.O